# Is this sequence of numbers related to partitions finite?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Define $T(n,k)$ = number of partitions of $n$ in which the greatest part is $k$, $1 \le k \le n$. The triangle for $n$ = {1,..,10} looks like:

1: [1]

2: [1, 1]

3: [1, 1, 1]

4: [1, 2, 1, 1]

5: [1, 2, 2, 1, 1]

6: [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1]

7: [1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]

8: [1, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

9: [1, 4, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

10: [1, 5, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

Let $P$ be the normal partition function, and let $T_m$ denote the $m^{th}$ row of $T(n,k)$. Notice that whenever $m=2P(n)$ for some integer $n$ then $T(m,2) = \frac{m}{2}$ and for some other $2 < k < m-2$, $T(m,k)$ also equals $\frac{m}{2}$. For example, let $m = 2P(4) = 10$, and note $T(10,2) = T(10,6) = 5$. A similar result is true for $m=2P(n)+1$; for example with $m = 2P(3)+1 = 7$, $T(7,2) = T(7,4) = 3$. So for every $m = 2P(n)$, there will be repeated values greater than 1 in the sequences $T_m$ and $T_{m+1}$.

For the values of $m = {8,13,19,26,34,43,46,68}$, none of which is equal to $2P(n)$ or $2P(n)+1$ for some integer $n$, there are repeated values greater than 1 in $T_m$:

8: [1, 4, $5$, $5$, 3, 2, 1, 1]

13: [1, 6, 14, $18$, $18$, 14, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

19: [1, 9, $30$, 54, 70, 71, 65, 52, 41, $30$, 22, 15, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

26: [1, 13, $56$, 136, 221, 282, 300, 288, 252, 212, 169, 133, 101, 77, $56$, 42, 30, 22, 15, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

34: [1, 17, 96, $297$, 603, 931, 1175, 1297, 1291, 1204, 1060, 905, 747, 608, 483, 383, $297$, 231, 176, 135, 101, 77, 56, 42, 30, 22, 15, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

43: [1, 21, 154, 588, 1469, 2702, 4011, 5066, $5708$, 5888, $5708$, 5262, 4691, 4057, 3446, 2871, 2369, 1928, 1563, 1251, 1001, 792, 627, 490, 385, 297, 231, 176, 135, 101, 77, 56, 42, 30, 22, 15, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

46: [1, 23, $176$, 720, 1898, 3692, 5731, 7564, 8824, 9418, 9373, 8877, 8073, 7139, 6158, 5231, 4370, 3621, 2965, 2417, 1951, 1573, 1255, 1002, 792, 627, 490, 385, 297, 231, $176$, 135, 101, 77, 56, 42, 30, 22, 15, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

68: [1, 34, $385$, 2280, 8529, 22856, 47527, 81457, 120092, 157564, 188556, 210005, 220877, 222118, 215415, 203067, 187013, 169120, 150614, 132559, 115463, 99795, 85628, 73088, 62049, 52490, 44210, 37143, 31088, 25970, 21618, 17970, 14881, 12310, 10143, 8349, 6842, 5604, 4565, 3718, 3010, 2436, 1958, 1575, 1255, 1002, 792, 627, 490, $385$, 297, 231, 176, 135, 101, 77, 56, 42, 30, 22, 15, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

I have checked up to $m=5,000$ and found no additional rows $T_m$ with $m >68$ that have repeated values greater than 1, except when $m$ can be written as $2P(n)$ or $2P(n)+1$ for some integer $n$. Is it possible that no more sporadic examples exist?

Comment: I don't understand your *"triangle"*. The partition function can be constructed with $p_1(n) = 1_{n \ge 0}, p_k(n) = \sum_{l \ge 0} p_{k-1}(n-lk), p(n) = p_n(n)$ which corresponds to the generating function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_k(n) q^n = \prod_{m=1}^k \frac{1}{1-q^m}$

Comment: @reuns The triangle is  https://oeis.org/A008284

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy Dover for prettifying my question.

Comment: If anyone answers this question it can be added to the comments in https://oeis.org/A292917